# В чем смысловое различие между словами?

Tags: выбор-слов

В чем смысловое различие между словами "прицепливаться" и "прицепляться"? В каких случаях употребляется "прицепливаться", а в каких - "прицепляться"?

Answer (score 4):

Видовая пара: **прицепиться ― прицепляться**. Нет глагола ***прицепливаться.***

Из словаря:

**ПРИЦЕПИТЬСЯ,**  св. 1. Зацепившись, прикрепиться, присоединиться. П. к трамваю. 2. Неодобр. Пристать к кому-л., начать надоедать; привязаться. Прицепился и не отстаёт. 3. Неодобр. Придраться. П. к пустяку.  4. Разг. Пристать к кому-л. (о болезни). Прицепился грипп.  <**Прицепляться, - нсв.**